# Wordpress header not scaling corectly for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I got a request today to help out a friend of a friend with her Wordpress site. I have never even looked at the Wordpress backend before today, but I agreed.

So, Im stuck now. Basically the header image is scaling totally wrong with mobile sizing. I'm not too used to Wordpress or that experienced of a coder so any help will be greatly appreciated!

[Here! Thanks!](http://fourlttrwrds.com)

Comment: You want to make it responsive ?

Comment: Yes please. I did some research on the theme, but I'm sure that she did less. If you have any advice... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you need to do is change this line :

```
.header-image{ background-size : cover; }
```

with this line :

```
.header-image{ background-size : 100% 100% !important; }
```

**NOTE:** Tested in Mozilla Browser only and its responsive.

Comment: Thank you! It's still not keeping the aspect ratio correct, but I feel like I can fix that.